# .htaccess subdomain and /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

how do I rewrite the URL:

**username**.domain.com/**file**

to

domain.com/q.php?user=**username**&url=**file**

Thanks.

Comment: belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/search?q=redirect+subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule .+ http://example.com/q.php?username=%1&file=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that is:

- dynamic (whatever the host is, it should work)
- easy to modify (= just change the first 'file' of the RewriteRule by the real file and it should work):

Tell me if it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.+(fr|com|net|org|eu)$
RewriteRule ^/(file)$ http://%3.%4/q.php?user=%2&url=$1
```